# BizTalk party configuration question

Tags: biztalk

I've never done party configuration for EDI files in BizTalk 2010, so I need some simple info.

I'm dropping xml files to BizTalk and creating HIPAA 835 files out. I get how you set up the basic party info to put all the appropriate information in the ISA and GS fields, but how do I set up a third party (i.e. US, THEM1 and THEM2)? I'm only dropping to a single send port, so how can I let BT know which party to use for which file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Send Port can only be associated with a single Party.  Messages being sent out the configured Send Port will have the party configuration applied to their ISA and GS fields after the responsible port has been identified by the EDI Send pipeline.

What you need to do is have multiple Send Ports configured to drop to a shared file-drop location, with a Promoted Property discerning between the messages that allows routing to the relevant Send Port.